# How would I generate the following sequence in Java using For Loops?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

body

I can work it out when it generates from -

Answer (score 2):

In your `for` loop, add an `if` statement to skip the 0.

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int start = -20;
    int end = 20;
    int step = 5;

    for(int i = start; i <= end; i+=step)
    {
      if(i != 0)
      {
        System.out.println(i);
      }

    }
}
```

Now it should be flexible for any other range excluding 0

Or you can just go with

```
for(int i = -20; i <= 20; i+=5)
{
    if(i != 0)
    {
      System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: This would include `0`.

Comment: removes the 0 now @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Curious: Why is upper limit a variable, but lower limit and increment are literals? Why name it `total`, since it in no way seems to indicate the sum of anything?

Comment: Edited for flexibility @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Why not just brute force it?

```
int [] sequence = {-20, -15, -10, -5, 5, 10, 15, 20};
for(int i : sequence ){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Or, to eliminate the `if` from the loop body:

```
for (int i = -20; i <= 20; i += (i == -5) ? 10 : 5) {
    // Do whatever you need with i, like System.out.println(i);
}
```

Or, if we want to get silly with an `if` statement:

```
for (int i = -20; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i != 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
        // Do whatever you need with i, like System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP didn't mention printing.

Comment: @shmosel Is that a problem? Do you think the OP is going to have trouble figuring out that the `println` is a placeholder for their code? Do you think they will wail and moan, "If only this approached worked for things *other* than printing! Oh, woe is me."?

Comment: @beaker Considering OP is trying to generate a sequence, the placeholder is `int sequence = {-20, -15, -10, -5, 5, 10, 15, 20}`, which probably doesn't help OP at all. What's done afterwards is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @shmosel Ah, so you made the assumption that the sequence is the goal rather than looping over the sequence values. Gotcha.

Comment: @beaker All I did was read the post title. Perhaps you have other methodologies?

Comment: @shmosel: by your criteria, I think my second solution is the only correct one so far. The loop itself generates the sequence.

Comment: @shmosel You interpreted the question differently than I did. Your original comment does not mention that you thought the loop was unnecessary, only the printing. Now that you've clarified your objection I'm sure we can let the OP decide.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a *single* `for` loop and add an `if` test for `0`, or use **two** loops. Like,

```
for (int i = -20; i < 0; i += 5) {
    // -20, -15, -10, -5
}
for (int i = 5; i <= 20; i += 5) {
   // 5, 10, 15, 20
}
```

**or**

```
for (int i = -20; i <= 20; i += 5) {
   if (i != 0) {
       // ...
   }
}
```